# Is it possible to create a Lost Update with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

I want to create a Lost Update with MySQL Workbench. Therefore, I have 2 connections to my database and 2 transactions. I also changed the transaction isolation level to read uncommitted but transaction A uses the current data when the update statement starts. It never uses the data from the first select statement and with select ... for update the transaction b is blocked.

Transaction A (starts first):

```
Start transaction;
SELECT * FROM table;
Select sleep(10);          -- <- Transaction B executes in this 10 seconds 
UPDATE table SET Number = Number + 10 WHERE FirstName = "Name1";
COMMIT;
```

Transaction B:

```
Start transaction;
UPDATE table SET Number = Number - 5 WHERE FirstName = "Name1";
COMMIT;
```

Is it possible to create this failure with MySQL Workbench. What´s wrong with my code?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The update in A work with data after the sleep is executed.  Select before does nothing in the transaction.